# how to add background color only for actived item in a <li> using styled component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Just wondering how can I add a background color for a active item using styed component? pretty much works like jQuery's add/remove class.

I have defined a active boolean variable in my state like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      placeholder: '',
      active: false,
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleImageError = this.handleImageError.bind(this);
  }
```

and a handleClick function can true active to true like this:

```
handleClick() {
    this.setState({ active: true });
  }
```

in my render function I have HTML like this:

```
 <MemberStyled className="member-item" active={active} onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <MemberStyled.avatar src={imgSource || placeholder} onError={this.handleImageError} />
        <MemberStyled.user>{name}</MemberStyled.user>
 </MemberStyled>
```

in member.styles.js file, I have style like this:

```
const MemberStyled = styled.li`
 background-color: ${props => props.active ? red : 'transparent'};
`;
```

Right now, all clicked items will change the color to red. How can I make only actived item to have red background in styled component?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you so much! It works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way for me is to save the index of your active element in the parentcomponent:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      placeholder: '',
      active: -1,
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleImageError = this.handleImageError.bind(this);
  }

  onClick(e, index) {
    this.setState({
      active: index,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { active } = this.state;
    return this.memberItems.map((itemData, index) => <MemberStyled active={index === active} itemKey={index} handleClick={() => handleClick(this, index)} />)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The idea is pretty much like the two answers above. They all work

Answer (score 1):

So all `member-item`s look to be part of a higher parent component. You should push out the active state to this parent. Then give each `member-item` a unique prop (index, or id should do). Then while calling the parent's `handleClick`, send it the unique number and the parent should store that instead of a boolean. Finally, in parent's render, compare the unique number prop value with active state value and send that as `active` boolean prop to `member-item`. Use this boolean in `member-item`'s render.

```
// in Parent Component
handleClick(activeKey){
   this.setState({activeKey});
}

isActive(key){
  const {activeKey} = this.state;
  return key === activeKey;
}

render(){
  return this.memberItems.map((index, itemData) => <MemberStyled active={this.isActive(index)} itemKey={index} handleClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, index)} />)
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I used your way to compare target item id to make this happens